# Mysql join inside of case

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, case

This does not work , how else can I structure this query ? 
Depending on the value of debtor_user_type field I need to join the appropriate table

```
SELECT * FROM invoice_headers

CASE 
WHEN invoice_headers.debtor_user_type = 0 
THEN

LEFT JOIN user_info 
ON invoice_headers.debtor_id = user_info.user_id    

ELSE

LEFT JOIN company_info 
ON invoice_headers.debtor_id = company_info.company_id    

END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **LEFT OUTER JOIN** with condition in ON clause.

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM invoice_headers A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_info B ON A.debtor_id = B.user_id AND A.debtor_user_type = 0 
LEFT OUTER JOIN company_info C ON A.debtor_id = C.company_id AND A.debtor_user_type <> 0
```